# How do I allow users to update database value only once and within the set limit

Tags: php, sql

I want to have a database in which I will have a column for max allowed value and another updatedValue. Admin will set the max allowed and the user will set the updated value which should not exceed the maxallowed. And I would like the user to be allowed to update the value only once. How do I limit to belowOR equal to the max value

Comment: You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and/or [constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html). And add your DBMS tag, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new column in database: `isUpdated`
set its default value to false
when user updates the value check if the value of the column is true or false.
if false
update the new value and set the column to true.
and if true:
then throw an error or warning that the value has already been updated

Comment: I would like to ask how do I make sure that the updates value is not more than the set max value?

Comment: @McChris_Made_It just compare the value while adding. for ex if you have the max value in a variable: `$max` then simply: `if($user_typed_value > $max) { // warn the user } else { // proceed with your work }`